# asp.net mvc 3 - MVC 3 Razor: Country selection drop down list

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, drop-down-menu, country

**My controller action code:**

```
ViewBag.country = from p in CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures & ~CultureTypes.NeutralCultures)
                              select new SelectListItem
                              {
                                  Text = p.EnglishName,
                                  Value = p.DisplayName
                              };
```

**View code:**

```
<dl>
   <dt>
    <label>
        Country:
    </label>
   </dt>
   <dd>
   @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Country, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.country)
   </dd>
<dl>
```

It generates a drop-down list of unsorted languages. But I need a drop-down list of sorted country list. Help Please!!!!

Comment: Maybe you have to wait for a moment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
ViewBag.country = from p in CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures & ~CultureTypes.NeutralCultures).OrderBy(c=>c.Name)
                          select new SelectListItem
                          {
                              Text = p.EnglishName,
                              Value = p.DisplayName
                          };
```

Answer (score 7):

Windows and/or .Net do not contain a list of all countries.

The list of languages/cultures is stable, countries come and go, or change name frequently.

<strike>Go to the ISO site, and you can [download a list of countries](http://www.iso.org/iso/list-en1-semic-3.txt) from their site. You have to download this list, and update your data frequently.</strike>

**Update**: The list of country codes is no longer freely distributed by ISO, more information [can be found on the iso.org site.](http://www.iso.org/iso/home/standards/country_codes.htm)

And you have to decide, if you want to include countries like Palestine on this list (Palestine is on this list, just an example of "new" countries). You would probably have to add them manually.

Comment: Are there any jQuery plugin that can be used to generate country list in mvc3????

Answer (score 0):

you can use this list

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.sLA.COUNTRYCODEPHONENUMBER, new SelectList(
                                    new[]{
                                    new{ value="44" ,Text ="UK (+44)"},
                                    new{ value="1",Text ="USA (+1)"},
                                    new{ value="213",Text ="Algeria (+213)"},
                                    new{ value="376",Text ="Andorra (+376)"},
                                    new{ value="244",Text ="Angola (+244)"},
                                    new{ value="1264",Text ="Anguilla (+1264)"},
                                    new{ value="1268",Text ="Antigua &amp; Barbuda (+1268)"},
                                    new{ value="54",Text ="Argentina (+54)"},
                                    new{ value="374",Text ="Armenia (+374)"},
                                    new{ value="297",Text ="Aruba (+297)"},
                                    new{ value="61",Text ="Australia (+61)"},
                                    new{ value="43",Text ="Austria (+43)"},
                                    new{ value="994",Text ="Azerbaijan (+994)"},
                                    new{ value="1242",Text ="Bahamas (+1242)"},
                                    new{ value="973",Text ="Bahrain (+973)"},
                                    new{ value="880",Text ="Bangladesh (+880)"},
                                    new{ value="1246",Text ="Barbados (+1246)"},
                                    new{ value="375",Text ="Belarus (+375)"},
                                    new{ value="32",Text ="Belgium (+32)"},
                                    new{ value="501",Text ="Belize (+501)"},
                                    new{ value="229",Text ="Benin (+229)"},
                                    new{ value="1441",Text ="Bermuda (+1441)"},
                                    new{ value="975",Text ="Bhutan (+975)"},
                                    new{ value="591",Text ="Bolivia (+591)"},
                                    new{ value="387",Text ="Bosnia Herzegovina (+387)"},
                                    new{ value="267",Text ="Botswana (+267)"},
                                    new{ value="55",Text ="Brazil (+55)"},
                                    new{ value="673",Text ="Brunei (+673)"},
                                    new{ value="359",Text ="Bulgaria (+359)"},
                                    new{ value="226",Text ="Burkina Faso (+226)"},
                                    new{ value="257",Text ="Burundi (+257)"},
                                    new{ value="855",Text ="Cambodia (+855)"},
                                    new{ value="237",Text ="Cameroon (+237)"},
                                    new{ value="1",Text ="Canada (+1)"},
                                    new{ value="238",Text ="Cape Verde Islands (+238)"},
                                    new{ value="1345",Text ="Cayman Islands (+1345)"},
                                    new{ value="236",Text ="Central African Republic (+236)"},
                                    new{ value="56",Text ="Chile (+56)"},
                                    new{ value="86",Text ="China (+86)"},
                                    new{ value="57",Text ="Colombia (+57)"},
                                    new{ value="269",Text ="Comoros (+269)"},
                                    new{ value="242",Text ="Congo (+242)"},
                                    new{ value="682",Text ="Cook Islands (+682)"},
                                    new{ value="506",Text ="Costa Rica (+506)"},
                                    new{ value="385",Text ="Croatia (+385)"},
                                    new{ value="53",Text ="Cuba (+53)"},
                                    new{ value="90392",Text ="Cyprus North (+90392)"},
                                    new{ value="357",Text ="Cyprus South (+357)"},
                                    new{ value="42",Text ="Czech Republic (+42)"},
                                    new{ value="45",Text ="Denmark (+45)"},
                                    new{ value="253",Text ="Djibouti (+253)"},
                                    new{ value="1809",Text ="Dominica (+1809)"},
                                    new{ value="1809",Text ="Dominican Republic (+1809)"},
                                    new{ value="593",Text ="Ecuador (+593)"},
                                    new{ value="20",Text ="Egypt (+20)"},
                                    new{ value="503",Text ="El Salvador (+503)"},
                                    new{ value="240",Text ="Equatorial Guinea (+240)"},
                                    new{ value="291",Text ="Eritrea (+291)"},
                                    new{ value="372",Text ="Estonia (+372)"},
                                    new{ value="251",Text ="Ethiopia (+251)"},
                                    new{ value="500",Text ="Falkland Islands (+500)"},
                                    new{ value="298",Text ="Faroe Islands (+298)"},
                                    new{ value="679",Text ="Fiji (+679)"},
                                    new{ value="358",Text ="Finland (+358)"},
                                    new{ value="33",Text ="France (+33)"},
                                    new{ value="594",Text ="French Guiana (+594)"},
                                    new{ value="689",Text ="French Polynesia (+689)"},
                                    new{ value="241",Text ="Gabon (+241)"},
                                    new{ value="220",Text ="Gambia (+220)"},
                                    new{ value="7880",Text ="Georgia (+7880)"},
                                    new{ value="49",Text ="Germany (+49)"},
                                    new{ value="233",Text ="Ghana (+233)"},
                                    new{ value="350",Text ="Gibraltar (+350)"},
                                    new{ value="30",Text ="Greece (+30)"},
                                    new{ value="299",Text ="Greenland (+299)"},
                                    new{ value="1473",Text ="Grenada (+1473)"},
                                    new{ value="590",Text ="Guadeloupe (+590)"},
                                    new{ value="671",Text ="Guam (+671)"},
                                    new{ value="502",Text ="Guatemala (+502)"},
                                    new{ value="224",Text ="Guinea (+224)"},
                                    new{ value="245",Text ="Guinea - Bissau (+245)"},
                                    new{ value="592",Text ="Guyana (+592)"},
                                    new{ value="509",Text ="Haiti (+509)"},
                                    new{ value="504",Text ="Honduras (+504)"},
                                    new{ value="852",Text ="Hong Kong (+852)"},
                                    new{ value="36",Text ="Hungary (+36)"},
                                    new{ value="354",Text ="Iceland (+354)"},
                                    new{ value="91",Text ="India (+91)"},
                                    new{ value="62",Text ="Indonesia (+62)"},
                                    new{ value="98",Text ="Iran (+98)"},
                                    new{ value="964",Text ="Iraq (+964)"},
                                    new{ value="353",Text ="Ireland (+353)"},
                                    new{ value="972",Text ="Israel (+972)"},
                                    new{ value="39",Text ="Italy (+39)"},
                                    new{ value="1876",Text ="Jamaica (+1876)"},
                                    new{ value="81",Text ="Japan (+81)"},
                                    new{ value="962",Text ="Jordan (+962)"},
                                    new{ value="7",Text ="Kazakhstan (+7)"},
                                    new{ value="254",Text ="Kenya (+254)"},
                                    new{ value="686",Text ="Kiribati (+686)"},
                                    new{ value="850",Text ="Korea North (+850)"},
                                    new{ value="82",Text ="Korea South (+82)"},
                                    new{ value="965",Text ="Kuwait (+965)"},
                                    new{ value="996",Text ="Kyrgyzstan (+996)"},
                                    new{ value="856",Text ="Laos (+856)"},
                                    new{ value="371",Text ="Latvia (+371)"},
                                    new{ value="961",Text ="Lebanon (+961)"},
                                    new{ value="266",Text ="Lesotho (+266)"},
                                    new{ value="231",Text ="Liberia (+231)"},
                                    new{ value="218",Text ="Libya (+218)"},
                                    new{ value="417",Text ="Liechtenstein (+417)"},
                                    new{ value="370",Text ="Lithuania (+370)"},
                                    new{ value="352",Text ="Luxembourg (+352)"},
                                    new{ value="853",Text ="Macao (+853)"},
                                    new{ value="389",Text ="Macedonia (+389)"},
                                    new{ value="261",Text ="Madagascar (+261)"},
                                    new{ value="265",Text ="Malawi (+265)"},
                                    new{ value="60",Text ="Malaysia (+60)"},
                                    new{ value="960",Text ="Maldives (+960)"},
                                    new{ value="223",Text ="Mali (+223)"},
                                    new{ value="356",Text ="Malta (+356)"},
                                    new{ value="692",Text ="Marshall Islands (+692)"},
                                    new{ value="596",Text ="Martinique (+596)"},
                                    new{ value="222",Text ="Mauritania (+222)"},
                                    new{ value="269",Text ="Mayotte (+269)"},
                                    new{ value="52",Text ="Mexico (+52)"},
                                    new{ value="691",Text ="Micronesia (+691)"},
                                    new{ value="373",Text ="Moldova (+373)"},
                                    new{ value="377",Text ="Monaco (+377)"},
                                    new{ value="976",Text ="Mongolia (+976)"},
                                    new{ value="1664",Text ="Montserrat (+1664)"},
                                    new{ value="212",Text ="Morocco (+212)"},
                                    new{ value="258",Text ="Mozambique (+258)"},
                                    new{ value="95",Text ="Myanmar (+95)"},
                                    new{ value="264",Text ="Namibia (+264)"},
                                    new{ value="674",Text ="Nauru (+674)"},
                                    new{ value="977",Text ="Nepal (+977)"},
                                    new{ value="31",Text ="Netherlands (+31)"},
                                    new{ value="687",Text ="New Caledonia (+687)"},
                                    new{ value="64",Text ="New Zealand (+64)"},
                                    new{ value="505",Text ="Nicaragua (+505)"},
                                    new{ value="227",Text ="Niger (+227)"},
                                    new{ value="234",Text ="Nigeria (+234)"},
                                    new{ value="683",Text ="Niue (+683)"},
                                    new{ value="672",Text ="Norfolk Islands (+672)"},
                                    new{ value="670",Text ="Northern Marianas (+670)"},
                                    new{ value="47",Text ="Norway (+47)"},
                                    new{ value="968",Text ="Oman (+968)"},
                                    new{ value="680",Text ="Palau (+680)"},
                                    new{ value="507",Text ="Panama (+507)"},
                                    new{ value="675",Text ="Papua New Guinea (+675)"},
                                    new{ value="595",Text ="Paraguay (+595)"},
                                    new{ value="51",Text ="Peru (+51)"},
                                    new{ value="63",Text ="Philippines (+63)"},
                                    new{ value="48",Text ="Poland (+48)"},
                                    new{ value="351",Text ="Portugal (+351)"},
                                    new{ value="1787",Text ="Puerto Rico (+1787)"},
                                    new{ value="974",Text ="Qatar (+974)"},
                                    new{ value="262",Text ="Reunion (+262)"},
                                    new{ value="40",Text ="Romania (+40)"},
                                    new{ value="7",Text ="Russia (+7)"},
                                    new{ value="250",Text ="Rwanda (+250)"},
                                    new{ value="378",Text ="San Marino (+378)"},
                                    new{ value="239",Text ="Sao Tome &amp; Principe (+239)"},
                                    new{ value="966",Text ="Saudi Arabia (+966)"},
                                    new{ value="221",Text ="Senegal (+221)"},
                                    new{ value="381",Text ="Serbia (+381)"},
                                    new{ value="248",Text ="Seychelles (+248)"},
                                    new{ value="232",Text ="Sierra Leone (+232)"},
                                    new{ value="65",Text ="Singapore (+65)"},
                                    new{ value="421",Text ="Slovak Republic (+421)"},
                                    new{ value="386",Text ="Slovenia (+386)"},
                                    new{ value="677",Text ="Solomon Islands (+677)"},
                                    new{ value="252",Text ="Somalia (+252)"},
                                    new{ value="27",Text ="South Africa (+27)"},
                                    new{ value="34",Text ="Spain (+34)"},
                                    new{ value="94",Text ="Sri Lanka (+94)"},
                                    new{ value="290",Text ="St. Helena (+290)"},
                                    new{ value="1869",Text ="St. Kitts (+1869)"},
                                    new{ value="1758",Text ="St. Lucia (+1758)"},
                                    new{ value="249",Text ="Sudan (+249)"},
                                    new{ value="597",Text ="Suriname (+597)"},
                                    new{ value="268",Text ="Swaziland (+268)"},
                                    new{ value="46",Text ="Sweden (+46)"},
                                    new{ value="41",Text ="Switzerland (+41)"},
                                    new{ value="963",Text ="Syria (+963)"},
                                    new{ value="886",Text ="Taiwan (+886)"},
                                    new{ value="7",Text ="Tajikstan (+7)"},
                                    new{ value="66",Text ="Thailand (+66)"},
                                    new{ value="228",Text ="Togo (+228)"},
                                    new{ value="676",Text ="Tonga (+676)"},
                                    new{ value="1868",Text ="Trinidad &amp; Tobago (+1868)"},
                                    new{ value="216",Text ="Tunisia (+216)"},
                                    new{ value="90",Text ="Turkey (+90)"},
                                    new{ value="7",Text ="Turkmenistan (+7)"},
                                    new{ value="993",Text ="Turkmenistan (+993)"},
                                    new{ value="1649",Text ="Turks &amp; Caicos Islands (+1649)"},
                                    new{ value="688",Text ="Tuvalu (+688)"},
                                    new{ value="256",Text ="Uganda (+256)"},
                                    new{ value="44",Text ="UK (+44)"},
                                    new{ value="380",Text ="Ukraine (+380)"},
                                    new{ value="971",Text ="United Arab Emirates (+971)"},
                                    new{ value="598",Text ="Uruguay (+598)"},
                                    new{ value="1",Text ="USA (+1)"},
                                    new{ value="7",Text ="Uzbekistan (+7)"},
                                    new{ value="678",Text ="Vanuatu (+678)"},
                                    new{ value="379",Text ="Vatican City (+379)"},
                                    new{ value="58",Text ="Venezuela (+58)"},
                                    new{ value="84",Text ="Vietnam (+84)"},
                                    new{ value="84",Text ="Virgin Islands - British (+1284)"},
                                    new{ value="84",Text ="Virgin Islands - US (+1340)"},
                                    new{ value="681",Text ="Wallis &amp; Futuna (+681)"},
                                    new{ value="969",Text ="Yemen (North)(+969)"},
                                    new{ value="967",Text ="Yemen (South)(+967)"},
                                    new{ value="260",Text ="Zambia (+260)"},
                                    new{ value="263",Text ="Zimbabwe (+263)"},
                                },
                                      "Value",
                                      "Text",
                                      Model), new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Nuget Package **CountryData.Standard.** Install it and use as follows:

```
using CountryData.Standard;

List countries = new List<SelectListItem>();
List<string> Countries = new CountryHelper().GetCountries();
foreach(var country in Countries) {
       countries.Add(new SelectListItem {Text = country, Value = country});
}
return countries;
```