# how to get list of all countries in world through google map API?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, google-maps

I am working on a project and in the registration page I want to get a list of all countries in a dropdown list through google API. i used cultureInfo but it get list of just unik 127 countries. i want to use google Map API. Can anyone please show me what I need to do in the Controller, the View and model or whatever is required ? I have a view of the registraion page

```
@model Retail_MVC.Models.registration
@{

    Layout = null;
}

<div class="my_wrapper">
         <div class="my_left_box">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.username)
         </div>
         <div class="my_right_box">
           <input type="text" id="txtusername" name="UserName"/>         
         </div>

   </div>
  -- here i want to get dropdownlist for all countries--
```

Comment: May I ask why do you need to use google map API?Otherwise this link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7763240/asp-net-mvc-3-mvc-3-razor-country-selection-drop-down-list) may help you.

Comment: i already used this method but it does not show all countries in world.