# JSON, how to get all countries from google MAP API

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, geolocation

I wondered and searched in google map api, how can i get JSON list of all countries (not autocomplete) in select box for example.

Comment: Check this: https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/autocomplete

Comment: There is this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14597389/how-to-get-list-of-all-countries-in-world-through-google-map-api and they say you can't.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot, but if you try googling "country list json" you'll find plenty of resources like [this](https://github.com/tarraq/JSON-data-arrays) or [this](https://github.com/mledoze/countries)